# How to Convert Kilometers/Kilogram (km/kg) to Miles/Gallon (MPG)

Tags: arithmetic, unit-of-measure

I need to convert Kilometers per Kilogram to Miles per Gallon in order to calculate the Carbon Footprint of daily work commuters with vehicles using CNG (Nat Gas).

In order to do this, I need to be able to figure the density of CNG. But, I am unsure of the pressure. The commuters are driving Natural Gas Vehicles. (http://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/bifueltech.shtml)

Not sure if this is correct, but I found this information: Mass density (kg/m³) = 0.712 from (http://www.unitrove.com/engineering/tools/gas/natural-gas-density)

The data entered by the users ranges between 8 and 20. Therefore, the result should come up with a similar number to miles per gallon.

Comment: Have a look at [UnitConvert](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html). Your question seems to contain some bits of irrelevant information. I don't see how your complaints about Diesel or commuters in India relate to your problem of unit conversion. I suggest improving your question to clarify this or just remove this information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the formula's are used to convert to meters/second?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46034/what-is-the-formulas-are-used-to-convert-to-meters-second)

Comment: I thought this was a math group. I see now that this is really a group for a specific piece of what seems to be expensive computer software. I need to do the conversion with my own formula. Maybe someone could direct me to the proper place to ask a math question online?

Comment: I shall migrate your question to [Math.SE].

Comment: You need to provide the density in kg/m^3 of the gas you are using otherwise it can't be done. If the CNG is pressurised that is the relevant figure.

Comment: Mass density (kg/m³) = 0.712

Comment: the density of compressed natural gas is mucn higher than tne numbers sbown here. you need to know the pressure.

that said are you sure you dont mean to calculate equivalent mpg?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_per_gallon_gasoline_equivalent

Comment: Very good point. The data coming for km/kg are numbers between 8 and 32. This comes out to terrible gas mileage. Sounds like maybe I should post another question or update this one. Not sure what to do.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: So just repeat the calculation below with the pressurized gas (ie mass) density to get the correct conversion factor and then multiply both sides of the equation by the figure for km/kg.

Comment: I understand what you mean by replacing the mass with the correct value. But, what do you mean by "multiply both sides of the equation by the figure for km/kg"?

Comment: You have measurements which are numbers 'in' km/kg (which actually means 'multiplied by' km/kg) and 'the equation' is the last line of calculations below with the section between the two equal signs taken out. So if you 'multiply both sides' it just means place the measured number in front of the km/kg on the left and multiply the same number by the 0.0016747... on the right. This results in the answer you want; and it is already 'in' (ie in front of) mile/gallon.

Comment: I was able to get some more information about the density of the CNG. (http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/what-is-the-density-of-compressed-natural-gas-used-for-natural-gas-vehicles#24991) But, if I plug that number into the formula here I get 74,399.95 miles per gallon.

Comment: The calculation I did was 435 X 0.00378541 X 0.621371 = 1.02318263874 for the conversion factor. That is, the mpg is just a bit more (nominally of course) than the km/kg for CNG. Remember, if you're doing algebra a/(b/c) = ac/b.

Comment: To clarify, if 1 = m kg/gallon then kg = gallon/m so n mile/(gallon/m) = nm mile/gallon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

km/kg to miles/gallon (US)

```
1 km = 0.621371 mile

1 gallon = 0.00378541 m^3  therefore  m^3 = 1 gallon / 0.00378541

gas density = 0.712 kg/m^3 = 0.712 kg / (1 gallon / 0.00378541)
            = 0.00269521192 kg/gallon
```

Set the above to 1, rearrange for kg and substitute:

```
km/kg = 0.621371 mile / 371.028338284 gallon = 0.0016747... mile/gallon
```

Answer (score 1):

$$1\frac{\text{km}}{\text{kg}}=1\frac{\text{km}}{\text{kg}}\cdot\frac{0.712\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}\cdot\frac{\text{mi}}{1.60934\text{km}}\cdot\frac{\text{m}^3}{264.172\text{gal}}=0.0016747\ldots\frac{\text{mi}}{\text{gal}}$$